# Angular Translate firefox and safari behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, safari, angular-translate

everything works fine in Chrome, just in Safari and Firefox it is not possible to change the language.

```
angular.module('angularApp')
.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.usePostCompiling(true)
    .useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'i18n/locale-',
        suffix: '.json'
    })
    .registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['de','en'],{
        'de_DE': 'de',
        'en-*': 'en'
    })
    .preferredLanguage('de')
    .determinePreferredLanguage()
    .fallbackLanguage('de');
}]);
```

In my Controller I use the following to change the language, which as already mentioned works in Chrome, but not in Safari and Firefox. No error is thrown and nothing comes up in the console.....

```
  .controller('NavbarCtrl', function ($scope, $translate) {


    $scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
      $translate.use(langKey).catch(function (err) {
        $translate.use($translate.fallbackLanguage());
      });
    };


  });
```

///// EDIT
I get the same error in Chrome, when I switch the language to English. For some reason the request to load the locale-de.json gets canceled.
[image]

Comment: Is your function `changeLanguage` being called in safari or firefox?

Comment: Yes it is: <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:auto;min-width:10px;background-color:transparent;padding:0;box-shadow:none;border:none">
            <li role="button" class="dropdown language-flag flag-icon-background flag-icon-de" ng-click="changeLanguage('de')"></li>
            <li role="button" class="dropdown language-flag flag-icon-background flag-icon-us" ng-click="changeLanguage('en')"></li>
          </ul> .... console.log logs out the change. It jut is not set.

Comment: Ok its really strange... Safari tells me, that there was en error, loading the resource. But why does Chrome manage to load it?

Comment: I changed the language in chrome to english and now I get the same error. For some reason the locale-de.json request gets canceled.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found why it was behaving weirdly. I rearranged the order in which $translateProvider laods the settings and also changed the fallbackLanguage:

```
.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider

    .useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'i18n/locale-',
        suffix: '.json'
    })
    .registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['de','en'],{
        'de_DE': 'de',
        'en_*': 'en'
    })
    .determinePreferredLanguage()
    .fallbackLanguage('de_DE')
    .useSanitizeValueStrategy(null)

}]);
```

Now the request doesn't get canceled anymore.